# Updating IIS website using WCF standard endpoints with Powershell

Tags: wcf, iis, powershell

We have an ASP.Net website running under the 4.0 framework in IIS 7.5 on a Windows Server 2008 R2 box.  A portion of the web site functionality utilizes WCF and has a "standardEndpoints" section in the web.config.

The website works fine and everything works fine if we want to use the IIS Management Console GUI to do things.

We would like to use powershell to make changes to the web.site but when we run "Set-WebConfigurationProperty" an error is generated indicating that the "standardEndpoints" section of the web.config can't be processed.

[image: Powershell Failure]

The hotfix referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643646/how-does-one-configure-the-authentication-of-an-iis-website-hosting-a-wcf-rest) is not the solution.  The website works, the hotfix appears to be only for Server 2008 (not R2), and when you try to install it, it says "not applicable for this server".

We did discover by running $PSVersionTable that PowerShell was referencing version 2.0 of the CLR.  We installed Powershell 3.0 and now Powershell is referencing version 4.0 of the CLR but the problem persists.

We are looking to see if there is a simple solution to this.  I suspect we may not have the right version of the IIS management script dll but can't find a different one to use.  If the solution gets to complicated, we will just wipe the server and start from scratch.

Thanks for any suggestions,

John

Comment: Is your app pool running the appropriate version of the framework?

Comment: Yes.  The website function fine when accessed via the IIS manager or from a web browser.  The only point we have a problem is the powershell command indicated.